# Proving convergence of $\frac{1}{n}W_n^\top W_n$ where $W_n\sim \mathrm{Mul}(n, \frac{1}{n}1_n)$

Tags: probability, asymptotics

I want to prove

$$\frac{1}{n}W_n^\top W_n \to2 \qquad \text{in probability.} $$

$W_n$ is a $n\times1$ vector st $W_n\sim \mathrm{Multinomial}(n, \frac{1}{n}1_n)$. I tried to find an upper bound of the variance but when I bounded the covariance with the variance (using Cauchy–Schwarz), I got $V(\frac{1}{n}W_n^\top W_n)\le 15$, which is not very useful.

Another approach that I was trying was as follows

Say $X_{i,n}\sim \mathrm{Multinomial}(1, \frac{1}{n}1_n)$. Then $W_n=\sum_{i=1}^n X_{i,n}$. This reduced the above problem to proving

$$\frac{2}{n}\sum_{1\le i<j\le n} X_{i,n}^\top X_{j,n} \to 1 \qquad\text{ in probability}$$

However, I'm not sure how to do this either. Maybe there is some version of WLLN that would work here? (As $E[X_{i,n}^\top X_{j,n}]=\frac 1n$). Another idea was to use asymptotic distribution result of U Statistic but that won't work either since the RVs depend on $n$. All hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $R_1, \ldots, R_n$ be independent RVs, each of which taking values in $\{1, \ldots, n\}$ with equal probabilities. Then by writing $X_i = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \mathbf{1}_{\{R_i = k\}} \vec{\mathrm{e}}_k $, we can realize $W_n$ as the sum of $X_1, \ldots, X_n$. Consequently,

$$ \frac{1}{n}W_n^{\top}W_n
= 1 + \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i \neq j} X_{i}^{\top}X_{j}
= 1 + \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i \neq j} \mathbf{1}_{\{R_i = R_j\}}. $$

This immediately shows that

$$\mathbf{E}\biggl[\frac{1}{n}W_n^{\top}W_n\biggr] = 1 + \frac{n-1}{n} \tag{1} $$

and hence $\mathbf{E}\bigl[\frac{1}{n}W_n^{\top}W_n\bigr] \to 2$. Moreover,

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{Var}\biggl(\frac{1}{n}W_n^{\top}W_n\biggr)
&= \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{\substack{i \neq j \\ k \neq l}} \mathbf{Cov}(\mathbf{1}_{\{R_i = R_j\}}, \mathbf{1}_{\{R_k = R_l\}}) \\
&= \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i, j, k, l \text{ distinct}} \underbrace{\mathbf{Cov}(\mathbf{1}_{\{R_i = R_j\}}, \mathbf{1}_{\{R_k = R_l\}})}_{=0 \text{ by independence}} \\
&\quad + \frac{4}{n^2} \sum_{i, j, k \text{ distinct}} \underbrace{\mathbf{Cov}(\mathbf{1}_{\{R_i = R_j\}}, \mathbf{1}_{\{R_i = R_k\}})}_{=0 \text{ by computation}} + \frac{2}{n^2} \sum_{i \neq j} \mathbf{Var}(\mathbf{1}_{\{R_i = R_j\}}) \\
&= \frac{2n(n-1)}{n^2} \cdot \frac{1}{n}\left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right) \\
&\leq \frac{2}{n} \tag{2}
\end{align*}

and hence $\frac{1}{n}W_n^{\top}W_n - \mathbf{E}\bigl[\frac{1}{n}W_n^{\top}W_n\bigr] \to 0$ in probability. Therefore the desired conclusion follows.